# Consuming a restful basic auth rest web service from a .net mvc 2.0 razor pagemodel application

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, restsharp

I need to consume a restful web service with basic authentication from a .net core razor pagemodel application.

This is all a part of a legacy project that needs a new UI to use some new components and it used to have a Webforms UI before.

I set a custom usermanager and a custom userstore. I can call the restful the methods I overwrote and I can sign in successfully.

However I need to have the user's username and password in every PageModel and I don't know how to retrieve the password after I log in.

For example when the user goes to the index page I need to retrieve something from the service

```
var client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cslLink"] +
                                                    "/BusinessEntityService.svc/GetMainItemGridView");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(User.Identity.Name, "hardcodedpassword");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            JsonArrayGridViewDataSOurce = response.Content;
```

I can get the username, but not the password.

Is there any way I can get the password?

Is there another way I can do this?

I can modify the service if I have to, but I have to do it as fast as possible with the least number of modifications.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to retrieve the password. It is stored as a one-way encrypted and salted hash. Even if you could get it, it wouldn't do you any good, as it's no longer the "password". When logging in, the password you enter is likewise salted and hashed and then simply compared to what's in the database. It's only via the comparison of the two hashes that the password can be validated, it's not comparing the literal password the user entered.

Comment: I know how to encrypt it, that wouldn't be an issue

Comment: I'm talking about *decryption*. The password should be stored as a one-way hash, meaning it cannot be decrypted, meaning there's no way to get the actual plain text password back. If you're not storing the passwords that way, that's a huge, gaping security hole.